# What is a module in C++?

Tags: c++, module, definition

What does the term *module* refer to in the following sentence?

> Don't allow exceptions to propagate across module boundaries.

This is rule 62 in [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu.

---

I have now read the book, so I would like to quote the section summary, which I think adds some clarity:

> Don't throw stones into your neighbor’s garden: There is no ubiquitous binary standard for C++ exception handling. Don't allow exceptions to propagate between two pieces of code unless you control the compiler and compiler options used to build both sides; otherwise, the modules might not support compatible implementations for exception propagation. Typically, this boils down to: Don’t let exceptions propagate across module/subsystem boundaries.

Comment: Ignore the two comments above. There is a new feature called *modules* proposed for a newer standard, but the quote from the book does not refer to this.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas So what is it referring to?

Comment: @Rapptz: I don't recall how modules were defined in the book, but the general idea is that compilers sometimes have issues handling exceptions that propagate from one shared object/dll to another. The use of *module* in the book relates to an aggregation of code that could in the future be implemented as a _module_, but the rules apply to C++03

Comment: Most likely he is talking about DLLs.

Comment: @AndyProwl And the weaknesses of some early versions of Visual Studios?  (We regularly propagate exceptions accross DLL boundaries, and have _never_ had any problems with it, at least with VS 2005 up and g++ 4.4.2 up.)

Comment: @emddudley - I'm curious. Have you read the indicated chapter? What does *it* say?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Probably. I would infer he's talking about DLLs because of how he uses the same term in other sentences from the same page.

Comment: @Robᵩ Unfortunately I do not have access to the book. I am researching the implications of using exceptions in my C++ code and I saw that phrase mentioned multiple places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a good question.  The C++ standard doesn't use the word
module (I don't think, at least), and the usual everyday meaning
is something like a translation unit.  Except that that can't be
what Herb and Andrei mean, since the real purpose of using
exceptions is to propagate up out of the local body of
code—otherwise, you'd use return codes.

I can only guess, but they probably mean something that might
reasonably be implemented in a different DLL.  Propagating
exceptions accross DLL boundaries *might* be a problem, if the
DLL's have been compiled with a different compiler, or use
a different language.  Otherwise...

It's usually considered best practice to have a single try/catch
block in main (or in some other high level function, in each
thread), and catch all exceptions there, regardless of where
they come from.  And there are no problems with modern compilers when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read that book but it sounds like it is most likely the module concept detailed in this [pdf from the University of Michigan](http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/CppHeaderFileGuidelines.pdf).

Ie. A Module is a single compilation unit that usually consists of a header file and a source file.

This makes sense in the context of your quote from the book since having control of compilation is emphasized. If you have self contained functionality in a single compilation unit (module) then you never have to worry about your compiled functionality becoming incomplete due to reliance on a particular compiler feature.